# ActiveDirectory domain service wizard: Prerequisites check for domain controller upgrade fails

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, prerequisites

I want to test my software's SSO, so I am trying to configure ActiveDirectory on Windows Server 2012, following [this tutorial](http://msftplayground.com/2012/06/install-sharepoint-2013-public-beta-on-windows-server-2012-rc-part-ii-installation-of-active-directory-and-dns-services-on-windows-server-2012-rc/).

At "prerequisites step", the window is supposed to look like:

[image]

but unfortunately I get an error:

[image]

Sorry for the Japanese, it says:

```
x The prerequisites check for the domain controller upgrade failed.
   The certificate server is installed.
i The prerequisites check is over.
x One of the above failed. Please correct and retry.
```

It seems that ActiveDirectory is already installed, but not configured.

Is there another way to enter the forest/domain name details, apart from this wizard?
Or should I uninstall ActiveDirectory, then restart the tutorial?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have already added the Active Directory Certificate Services before promoting it to a Domain Controller, remove the Certificate Services role, and then add the AD DS role again.

If the "Add Roles and Features" wizard does not allow you to remove Active Directory Certificate Services" (checkbox is greyed out), then you can remove it using the following PowerShell command:

```
Remove-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Certificate
```

See also: https://serverfault.com/a/717841/239616

Comment: Here is my understanding of your answer, is it correct? 1) Remove AD CS, 2) Promote to domain server, 3) Add AD CS

Comment: Exactly! Remove ADCS role, add ADDS role, add ADCS role again

Answer (score 0):

The removal of certificates worked in my case too for clearing off the pre-requisite failure. 
I'm pasting a powershell command in case the GUI does not work

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the answer by Mathias R. Jessen.

```
Remove-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Certificate
```

as a PowerShell command; however, if the option Network Device Enrollment Service is already installed, so the above command will be not enough before uninstalling this feature:

```
PS C:\> Uninstall-AdcsNetworkDeviceEnrollmentService -Force
```

Now, retry Mathias's solution and would work now ;-)