# Remove active directory certificate services role

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, service, windows-service

I have logged in as Administrator to my windows 2012 server. 
I just installed active directory certificate services role, now I want to remove it (as this service prevents me from adding my server to a domain) but the roles are grayed out. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're running the Remove Roles and Features wizard?

You can also try to remove the role via Powershell. Run Powershell as an Administrator then type the following in the console.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Certificate
```

Comment: Well I'm not an expert but I have used adding/removing roles many many times on windows servers 2003,2008,2012 but however this power shell solved the problem. thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah I asked the question only because I know I have accidentally used the wrong wizard before haha. I am glad the Powershell command solved your problem!